# Rails: model_url for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Let's say I have the simple rails blog app.

And I have a custom action, like `page_views` which shows the number of views of the post.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def page_views
     #show some page views
  end

end
```

And there is also an associated view in the `app/views/Posts` folder.

Now, in the `routes.rb` I have:

```
map.resources :posts

map.resources :posts, :collection => {
                                      :page_views=> :get
                                      }
```

in my posts `show.html.erb` file I have a link to the `page_views` view:

```
link_to("View Page Views",page_views_posts_path + "/" + post.id.to_s)
```

Another `paths`:

```
page_views_posts_path(post)
page_views_path(post)
page_views_posts(post)
```

Have either resulted in method not found or an incorrect url, like:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/page_views.#<posts:0xabcdef00>
```

I would assume the url should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/page_views/1
```

So, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide `page_views` page for each view you should declare extra action not as collection method but as a member method:

```
map.resources :posts, :member => { :page_views=> :get }
```

Also if you want this for all posts as well (show the ranking table of some sorts) add the same parameter as collection action:

```
map.resources :posts, :member => { :page_views=> :get }, :collection => { :page_views => :get }
```

This way you'll have following routes generated:

```
page_views_post_path(post) # for single post
page_views_posts_path      # for all posts
```

You can check new routes by running following command:

```
$ rake routes | grep page_views
```

You will get only those associated views considering the fact that you haven't declared them for other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add custom methods to resources in `routes.rb` like this:

```rb
resources :posts do 
  collection do
    get :page_views
  end
end
```

And use `page_views_posts_path` to access to the custom method.